# Unions used like Classes/Structs

Tags: c++, unions

I was trying to learn more about unions and their usefulness, when I was surprised that the following code is perfectly valid and works exactly as expected:

```
template <class T>
union Foo
{
    T a;
    float b;

    Foo(const T& value)
        : a(value)
    {
    }

    Foo(float f)
        : b(f)
    {
    }

    void bar()
    {
    }

    ~Foo()
    {
    }
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    Foo<int> foo1(12.0f);
    Foo<int> foo2((int) 12);

    foo1.bar();
    foo2.bar();

    int s = sizeof(foo1); // s = 4, correct

    return 0;
}
```

Until now, I had no idea that it is legal to declare unions with templates, constructors, destructor, and even member functions. In case it's relevant, I'm using Visual Studio 2012.

When I searched the internet to find more about using unions in this manner, I found nothing. Is this a new feature of C++, or something specific to MSVC? If not, I'd like to learn more about unions, specifically examples of them used like classes (above). If someone could point me to a more detailed explanation of unions and their usage as data structures, it'd be much appreciated.

Comment: 2003 Standard, 9.5 Unions, paragraph 1 `"... A union can have member functions (including constructors and destructors), but not virtual
(10.3) functions. ..."` So not new. Just uncommon. In terms of templates, I can't find any special wording, but I'm pretty sure it is treated as a `class` in this respect (in the same way there is no special wording for `struct`s).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this a new feature of C++, or something specific to MSVC?

No, as BoBtFish said, the 2003 C++ standard section `9.5 Unions` paragraph `1` says:

> [...] A union **can have member functions (including constructors and destructors)**, but not virtual (10.3) functions. A union shall not have base classes. A union shall not be used as a base class. An object of a class with a non-trivial constructor (12.1), a non-trivial copy constructor (12.8), a non-trivial destructor (12.4), or a non-trivial copy assignment operator (13.5.3, 12.8) cannot be a member of a union, nor can an array of such objects. If a union contains a static data member, or a member of reference type, the program is ill-formed.

`union`s do come under section `9 Classes` and the grammar for class-key is as follows:

```
class-key:
   class
   struct
   union
```

So acts like a `class` but has many more restrictions. The key restriction being that `unions` can only have one active non-static member at a time, which is also covered in paragraph `1`:

> In a union, **at most one of the non-static data members can be active at any time**, that is, the value of at most one of the non-static data members can be stored in a union at any time. [...]

The wording in the [`C++11 draft standard`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3485.pdf) is similar so it has not changed too much since `2003`.

As for the use of a `union`, there are two common reasons which are covered from different angles in this previous thread [C/C++: When would anyone use a union? Is it basically a remnant from the C only days?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4788965/c-c-when-would-anyone-use-a-union-is-it-basically-a-remnant-from-the-c-only) to summarize:

- To implement your own [`Variant type`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variant_type), a `union` gives you the ability to represent all the varying types without wasting memory. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4789053) to the thread gives a good example.
- [`Type punning`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_punning) but I would read [`Understanding Strict Aliasing`](http://cellperformance.beyond3d.com/articles/2006/06/understanding-strict-aliasing.html) as well since there are many cases where `type punning` is [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4284119) to [`Unions cannot be used as Base class`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4075643/unions-as-base-class) gives some really great insight into why `unions` are implemented as they are in `C++`.