# How function overload lookup works when one of the functions does not compile?

Tags: c++, templates, sfinae

So I quite do not understand how compiler chooses function overloads. I've thought that I understand until this code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template<class T>
struct base_type:
    public T
{
};

template<class T>
void check(T (&)[sizeof(base_type<T>)/sizeof(base_type<T>)]) {std::cout << "yeah";}

template<class T>
void check(T) {std::cout << "nah";}

union U{};
struct S{};

int main()
{
    U u[1];
    S s[1];

    check(u); // compile error
    check(s);

    return 0;
}
```

Why compiler did not choose 2d overload of `check(T)` when it has failed to check size of the array reference in fist overload?

Comment: Since you went to the trouble of stating `// compiler error`, you may as well actually state verbatim what the error actually *is* as part of your question. Just saying. You may also consider including from what source you obtained this code, and what *that* source has to say about it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why union can't be used in Inheritance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3615001/why-union-cant-be-used-in-inheritance)

Comment: "overloads" is a red herring – the issue rather is that you cannot inherit from unions, see link to duplicate.

Comment: This is *not at all* a duplicate of the linked question. OP is asking why SFINAE did not discard `check<U>`, not why it is not suitable.

Comment: @YSC exactly, thank you

Comment: Isn't this: `sizeof(base_type<T>)/sizeof(base_type<T>)` one by definition? Did you intend to determine the element size of the array instead?

Comment: @doug it is, this is the point

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only errors from the [immediate context](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15261234/481267) cause a "soft" error that removes the function template from the overload set. The compiler must instantiate `base_type<T>` before it can evaluate `sizeof(base_type<T>)`, and any errors resulting from that instantiation are *not* in the immediate context, and cause hard errors.

I am not sure what you are really trying to do, but you can probably do it using `std::enable_if_t<std::is_union_v<T>>` to disable the overload. The reason why this works is that the instantiation of `std::enable_if` which is done first causes no errors; the resulting class simply may not contain a member named `type`. The access to `type` *is* in the immediate context.

Comment: Thank you for useful link. So there is no way one could check in compile-time if type can be parent without hard compiler error? (do not mention type_traits)

Comment: @AlexanderG. I'm not aware of any way to do so. Even if you were willing to use type traits, there's no type trait to check whether a class is final.

Answer (score 2):

SFINAE occurs at declaration, not definition, and declaration of `base_type<U>` is fine, but produces hard error for its definition.

Standard provides traits `std::is_union` and `std::enable_if` to do SFINAE:

```
template<class T, std::enable_if_t<!std::is_union<T>::value, int> = 0>
void check(T (&)[1]) {std::cout << "yeah";}
```

And with C++17, you might even use `if constexpr` inside the function directly (even if simple `if` is ok in your simplified case):

```
template<class T>
void check(T (&)[1])
{
    if constexpr(std::is_union<T>::value) {
        std::cout << "nah";
    } else {
        std::cout << "yeah";
    }
}
```

Comment: The first template could use `std::is_union` to disallow it from consideration, so it SFINAE drops out.  https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_union

Comment: ^^^^^ `std::enable_if_t<!std::is_union<T>::value, void> check(T etc...)`

Answer (score 2):

Also I've found standard quote that might backup the answers.

Standard quote, C++11 §14.8.2/8:

> Only invalid types and expressions in the immediate context of the function type and its template parameter types can result in a
>   deduction failure. [ Note: The evaluation of the substituted types and
>   expressions can result in side effects such as the instantiation of
>   class template specializations and/or function template
>   specializations, the generation of implicitly-defined functions, etc.
>   Such side effects are not in the “immediate context” and can result in
>   the program being ill-formed. — end note ]